# Issues regarding my Python based Discord bot. I just wanted to make a bot that sends a message once a day at a defined time within a server

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
import discord
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands
import pytz

TOKEN = 'my token'
BOT_PREFIX = '?'
SEND_TIME = '16:40'  # time is in 24hr format
MESSAGE_CHANNEL_ID = mychannelid  # channel ID to send messages to
SERVER_ID = myserverid # replace with your server ID

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
tz = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
current_time = datetime.now(tz)
formatted_time = current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(formatted_time)

async def time_check(bot):
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(MESSAGE_CHANNEL_ID)
    while not bot.is_closed():
        now = datetime.now(tz).strftime('%H:%M')
        print('Checking time:', now)
        if now == SEND_TIME:
            print('Sending message...')
            guild = bot.get_guild(SERVER_ID)
            try:
                await message_channel.send("This is a regular message.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error sending message: {e}")
            time = 20  # wait for 20 seconds before checking again
        else:
            time = 1  # wait for 1 second before checking again
        await asyncio.sleep(time)

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('pong')

async def main():
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX, intents=intents)

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="with code"))

    await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))


    await bot.start(TOKEN)

    bot.loop.create_task(time_check(bot))
    await bot.wait_until_closed()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I have tried to change variables and add specific ones with no luck. In my actual code, I have all of the data filled out. I also created and added the bot to the server with admin perms. The bot does respond to one on one ?ping requests but, won't do it anywhere else. Anything helps thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an easier way to send a message on a regular basis.

Every heard the term cronjob? If not, read about it here: [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/)

To implement something like that, simply follow the documentation:

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
import pytz


tz = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern") # Your timezone


class YourClass(commands.Cog, name='YourClassName'):
    """Random text"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone=tz)
        scheduler.add_job(self.daily_message, CronTrigger(hour=X, minute=X, second=X), misfire_grace_time=X)
        scheduler.start()

async def daily_message(self):

# Get the guild here, load the message and whatver you need
```

Please note that this example got implemented into a `Cog` system. You need to re-code it if you want to integrate it into your code.

What the code basically does is the following:

- It gets executed on a daily basis at X hours, X minutes and X seconds (You can also change it to weekdays, only use hours or minutes etc.)
- `misfire_grace_time` makes sure that if the task is behind, it still tries to get executed within the range of seconds you specify. You can also set it to `None`
- Your function, I named it `daily_message` in this case, takes care of the rest. Get the guild in here, define the message and send it into a channel