# Bot post a embed message on specific days

Tags: python, loops, discord

I'm trying to get my bot to post a message in a specific channel on a specific day and time.

This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import datetime


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.all())

@tasks.loop(time=datetime.time(hour=22, minute=10))
async def job_loop():
    weekday = datetime.datetime.utcnow().weekday()
    if weekday == 5:
        channel = bot.get_channel(1147675545992167445)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="***Fridays Patrol!***",description="TESTTTTTTT",color=0x7289da)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # you need to start the loop
    if not job_loop.is_running():
        job_loop.start()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

The bot start but nothing happens

Bot to post a message every friday at 10pm

Comment: I gave an answer to a similar question a few weeks ago. You might want to check it out here: [I just wanted to make a bot that sends a message once a day at a defined time within a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75908758/issues-regarding-my-python-based-discord-bot-i-just-wanted-to-make-a-bot-that-s/75912086#75912086). For a more consistent way, you might want to look at a cronjob/[apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/) like I mentioned in my answer